# can you alias to a position inside a file?

Tags: symlink, alias

Is there a way to create an alias that will open a pdf or other document to a particular position? For example, I have a 105 page pdf which I want to alias/shortcut to in a directory on my system. But I actually need page 36 of that file and I want an easy way to get there. Is there a way to create an alias that will open the pdf at page 36?

Comment: That will depend strongly on what program you use to open them. `evince`, for example, has a `-p` switch to open the specified page.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Do you mean `-i, --page-index` option?

Comment: In any case, that is irrelevant to aliases or symlinks.  The only way this could be relevant here is to make a shell script to do it.

Comment: @Costas: both exist, they do different things if the page numbers in your pdf are i, ii, iii, iv, 1, 2, 3,… (`-p 3` will give you the page that has page number 3, `-i 3` will give you the third page, even if that says "ii" at the bottom.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'aliases' usually refer to [command line aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) in shells, which may not be what you want if you're using a GUI. The closest thing to 'shortcuts' for files are symbolic links, but they are just a way of referencing a file by another name, not something that can be used to give command line arguments to a program.

A simple shell script may be the closest bet. E.g. create a file with the following content, and make it executable (`chmod +x /path/to/the/script`):

```
#!/bin/sh
evince --page-label=36 /path/to/the/file.pdf
```

Running the script should launch `evince` and ask it to open the given file, on the given page.

As mentioned in the comments, the options required to open a document on a given position depend totally on the program. For evince, the `--page-label` parameter is mentioned in the [command line help](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/commandline.html.en). Many (text mode) text editors and `less` support the option `+NNN` to jump to *line* NNN when opening a file. On the other hand, LibreOffice apparently saves the last viewed position *per user* in some cases. Check your programs' manuals.

Comment: An argument in an alias is ok. `alias page36="evince --page-label=36 /path/to/the/file.pdf"`

Comment: @tomas, sure, aliases with arguments for `ls` are likely the most common use. But aliases only work on the command line.

Comment: no idea why I didn't set this as the accepted answer before. Sorry better late than never!